# SetCursorPos after SetForegroundWindow

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, cursor-position

I've got a problem in C# with SetCursorPos, the  SetCursorPos  doesn't work after  SetForegroundWindow. it returns error 2.

Part of Code:

```
Rect patrat = new Rect();
GetWindowRect(parinte, ref patrat);        
Console.WriteLine(SetForegroundWindow(parinte));
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine(SetCursorPos(patrat.Left + 10, patrat.Top + 20));
```

But if i put SetCursorPos before SetForegroundWindow it works

And this is the import of methods

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int SetCursorPos(int x, int y);



public struct Rect
    {
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Right { get; set; }
        public int Bottom { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT:I've discovered that with a certain program in foreground  SetCursorPos refuse to change cursor, what can i do ?

Comment: Does the "certain program" run under another user and/or with elevated privileges? If so, you might have to do so as well, although this shouldn't influence `SetCursorPos()`. Maybe the other program(s) got the cursor locked and/or reset it immediately (like many shooters do)?

Comment: no, i don;t run it under another user, and it doesn't block curosr, i can move it with mouse but i can change with setcursorpos

Comment: `SetCursorPos` returns a non-zero value to indicate success. You are not checking for errors in the call to `GetWindowRect`. You cannot check for errors in any of your p/invokes because you did not set `SetLastError` to `true`. Your `Rect` struct looks wrong to me. Don't use automatic properties. Use real fields.

Comment: SetCursorPos return always false ! the GetWindowRect alway return the good coordonates , but i cant setcursorpos when that program is set as forground windows , that program is (startrade 360)

Answer (score -1):

Running Visual Studio as Administrator should solve your problem.

[SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(WINUSER%2FSetForegroundWindow);k(SetForegroundWindow);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true) assigns a slightly higher priority to the thread that set the foreground window than it does to the foreground window. Therefore, you need to run your program with higher privileges than your foreground window has.